# Compilation error in undertow

Tags: java, maven, undertow

I am developing a webapp using undertow and am fairly new to java. I get an error while running ServeletEngine.java. I checked other relevant posts but they haven't solved my query. Please help me.

Error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project undertow-server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

My directory structure is: 
~/undertow-server/src/main/java/com/mastertheboss/undertow/ServeletEngine.java

My pom.xml file is: 
    $ cat ~/undertow-server/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mastertheboss.undertow</groupId>
  <artifactId>undertow-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>undertow-server</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
      <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
      <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.1</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                 </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.mastertheboss.undertow.ServeletEngine</mainClass>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

ServeletEngine.java is at:
$ cat ~/undertow-server/src/main/java/com/mastertheboss/undertow/ServletEngine.java 
    package com.mastertheboss.undertow;
    import io.undertow.Undertow;
    import io.undertow.server.*;
    import io.undertow.util.Headers;

```
public class ServletEngine {


    public static final String MYAPP = "/myapp";

    public static void main(final String[] args)  {

            try {

                DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
                        .setClassLoader(ServletEngine.class.getClassLoader())
                        .setContextPath(MYAPP)
                        .setDeploymentName("test.war")
                        .addListener(new ListenerInfo(MySessionListener.class))

                        .addServlets(
                                servlet("App", App.class)
                                        .addInitParam("message", "Hello World Implementing Servelets")    
                                        .addMapping("/myservlet"));

                DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
                manager.deploy();

                HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();
                PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(MYAPP))
                        .addPrefixPath(MYAPP, servletHandler);
                Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                        .setHandler(path)
                        .build();
                server.start();
            }  catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Which version of Java ?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"

Comment: Well... I don't undestand. I've copy-paste your two files, fixed the mainClass name and added a simple MySessionListener class and a simple App servlet. Guess what ? It works, when I launch `mvn compile exec:java`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for trying it out. Can you help me with a detailed answer? What is in your MySessionListener class and in the App servelet? And what is their location?

Comment: I've put the classes in the com.mastertheboss.undertow package. MySessionListener implements EventListener and is empty. App extends HttpServlet and override doGet with 1 line : `resp.getWriter().write("OK");`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that on your pom.xml, the class name is incorrect:

```
<mainClass>com.mastertheboss.undertow.ServeletEngine</mainClass>
```

It should be:

```
<mainClass>com.mastertheboss.undertow.ServletEngine</mainClass>
```

Am I right?

Regards!